# How to Add Count from another table to Crosstab query

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, crosstab

This is my first time trying crosstab queries in an Access database. I am trying to get the count information I need from two tables into a query so I can place the information in a report based on that query. I could probably do a subreport, but it would be nice for the information to be in the same table.

This is my current SQL code:

```
TRANSFORM Count(RequestTable.RequestID) AS CountRQ
SELECT PatronTable.Department, Count(RequestTable.RequestID) AS SumRQ
FROM PatronTable INNER JOIN RequestTable ON PatronTable.PatronID = RequestTable.PatronID
GROUP BY PatronDatabase.Department
PIVOT PatronDatabase.PatronType;
```

I want to add a Row Header count of how many Patron ID's are in each department.

This is my SQL when I add the row header:

```
TRANSFORM Count(RequestTable.RequestID) AS CountRQ
SELECT PatronDatabase.Department, Count(RequestTable.RequestID) AS SumRQ, Count(PatronDatabase.PatronID) AS PatronCount
FROM PatronDatabase INNER JOIN RequestTable ON PatronDatabase.PatronID = RequestTable.PatronID
GROUP BY PatronDatabase.Department
PIVOT PatronDatabase.PatronType;
```

However the PatronCount totals are wrong. PatronCount (count of people in each dept) ends up with the same number as SumRQ (sum count of requests in each dept), when the numbers should be less. I've been playing around with it and I can't seem to fix it.

As additional information, there is a one to many relationship between the tables PatronDatabase (one) and RequestTable (many).

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: I ended up using Stacked Queries and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Stacked Queries and this solved the problem. By stacking earlier queries together (queries referencing queries with the correct totals) I was eventually able to build a query that had all of the information I wanted for the form.